# Firebase observer reading data twice

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My observer listens for new `room`s being added in Firebase then updates a local array when one is added. It's working except when I add a room to Firebase, two of that room are added to the array. For example if I have 4 rooms in Firebase (Room One, Room Two, etc), when the app loads, there are 8 rooms in the table view (two Room One's, two Room Two's, etc). Then adding, for example, Room Five, two Room Fives would show up.

```
private func observeRooms() {

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {print("Error getting user UID"); return}
    let userRoomRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("rooms")

    userRoomRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (roomSnap) in
        for eachRoom in roomSnap.value as! [String : AnyObject] {
            let roomID = eachRoom.key as! String
            print("Roomsnap 2 (observer): \(roomSnap.value)")

            if let roomInfo = roomSnap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

                guard let roomName = roomInfo["roomName"] as! String! else {print("Error getting room name"); return}
                guard let participants = roomInfo["participants"] as! [String]! else {print("Error getting room participants"); return}
                print("\n\nRoom Name: \(roomName)\nRoom Participants: \(participants)\nRoom ID: \(roomID)\n")

                self.usersRooms.append(Room(id: roomID, name: roomName, participants: participants))

                print("User's Rooms: \(self.usersRooms)\n")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

        }
    })
}
```

Why is the data being fetched twice? Is there a way to write the function to just read each room once?

Firebase DB JSON:

```
"tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : {
  "gender" : "male",
  "handle" : "TestHandleOne",
  "name" : "Timothy",
  "profilePicture" : "https://graph.facebook.com/*removed*/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1",
  "rooms" : {
    "-KhY2GnJOxBwdPK669ui" : {
      "participants" : [ "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" ],
      "roomName" : "Room One"
    },
    "-KhY2Hnz48lTtRpzmBuw" : {
      "participants" : [ "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" ],
      "roomName" : "Room Two"
    },
    "-KhY2IZL4l16dMxGopt6" : {
      "participants" : [ "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" ],
      "roomName" : "Room Three"
    },
    "-KhY8SdHnkfI7bZIpyjI" : {
      "participants" : [ "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" ],
      "roomName" : "Room Four"
    }
  }
}
```

`roomSnap.value` printed to the console, each room printed twice with different values for Room ID. This is Room One for example:

[image]

Working function (final edit):

```
private func observeRooms() {

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {print("Error getting user UID"); return}
    let userRoomRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("rooms")


    roomRefHandle = userRoomRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        let roomData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        let id = snapshot.key
        guard let name = roomData["roomName"] as! String! else {print("Error getting user name"); return}

        self.usersRooms.append(Room(id: id, name: name, participants: [uid]))

        // Add new room to "rooms" in Firebase
        let roomDict = ["roomName" : name, "participants": [uid]] as [String : Any]
        let newRoomRef = self.roomRef.child(id)
        newRoomRef.setValue(roomDict)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `observeRooms` method?

Comment: In `viewDidAppear`

Comment: There's a lot of redundancy in that code and the .childAdded observer is not being utilized correctly - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .childAdded function reads in each child, one at a time, when first called and then any new children thereafter.

> This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again
>   every time a new child is added to the specified path. The listener is
>   passed a snapshot containing the new child's data.

The key here is that it automatically iterates over *each room in the node* one at a time. The code in the question is redundant which leads to multiple entries in the array.

Here's a super short way to populate the array with each child node

```
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")

    let uid = "user_0" //some uid
    let userRoomRef = usersRef.child(uid).child("rooms")

    userRoomRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { roomSnap in

        let roomDict = roomSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]

        let roomID = roomSnap.key
        let roomName = roomDict["roomName"] as! String
        print("roomID = \(roomID)  roomName = \(roomName)")

        var aRoom = Room() //could also initWith...
        aRoom.id = key
        aRoom.name = roomName
        //aRoom.participants = partipants
        self.usersRooms.append(aRoom)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

**Edit**

In response to a comment, an alternative structure is

```
users
  uid_0
   name: "Tom"
  uid_1
   name: "Jerry"

rooms
  room_0
   name: "Cool Room"
    users:
     uid_0: true
     uid_1: true
  room_1
   name: "Romper Room"
    users
     uid_0: true
```

Tom and Jerry both belong to the Cool Room, but only Tom belongs to Romper Room.

If you want to populate an array/tableView with the rooms that Tom belongs do, you can simply deep query on the rooms/users/ where uid_0 == true.

Comment: Hey Jay, thanks! I actually got it working a bit differently, I updated my question with the working code at the bottom. I can give your way a shot if you think it's more efficient/better - you seem to know Firebase pretty well so I'll trust you. So just to fully understand what was going wrong before - I was previously reading each room twice because when I added a room, the observer read that room PLUS all the other rooms?

Comment: @KingTim .childAdded reads in each room, one at a time, so it wouldn't make sense to iterate over rooms with *for eachRoom in roomSnap* since you only have one room. What I think is happening is that the for loop is attempting to loop over each *child node* in each room, therefore adding the whole room twice since there are two children; roomName and roomParticipants. There's a lot of un-needed code in the Working Function section; like newRoomRef var as it doesn't do anything. Follow the design pattern in my answer, just add a if let on the firebase key assignments in case they don't exist.

Comment: I tried this, and actually got a crash - I had to make some minor changes for it to compile, I can post what I tried if you’d like, as it was likely my changes that broke it. But I'll explain the extra code in my working solution maybe that will end up being an ok way of doing it:

Comment: To explain the extra code in the previous working solution, for example the `newRoomRef`, that’s to add the room to a different node called “rooms” in Firebase. The way I have my DB set up is that there is a “rooms” node, which holds ALL of the rooms that exist in the app, then each user has their own “rooms” node that holds only the rooms they belong to (this is so they only see their rooms in the table view, and not the rooms of every user on the app).

Comment: I want to make sure, since each room exists in two places in the database, that they both have the same ID. So, when a new room is created, it is set to the user’s “rooms” in firebase and given a unique ID using childByAutoID. Then, in `observeRooms`, that room is read and set to the global “rooms” node in Firebase, using the key so the room’s ID is the same. The global “rooms” in Firebase hold one extra thing that the user’s rooms don’t and that’s the messages. Hopefully that’s a logical way to have the DB set up - if you ever get 5 mins I’d love to chat about that and get your input.

Comment: @KingTim The code I posted doesn't crash as long as the Firebase structure matches the code. I think you missed the point of my answer though. *Your code reads in ONE and only ONE room.* It then tries to iterate over the rooms in the snapshot. That won't work as there is only ONE room in the snapshot - that's how .childAdded works... it retrieves ONE node at a time. It will retrieve room KhY2GnJOxBwdPK669ui, and it's children. Then it will then retrieve room KhY2Hnz48lTtRpzmBuw. etc. The FOR loop is meaningless as there are no rooms to iterate over - just one per event.

Comment: I think you might still be looking at the original function; the updated, working function is at the bottom of my question, which doesn't use a for loop.

Comment: Correct. I was clarifying the issue. The 'Working Code' has a number of issues as well as I pointed out in a prior comment. For example *newRoomRef* doesn't do anything and *name.characters.count > 0* doesn't either as Firebase will not store empty strings. You're also redefining uid with *if let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {* since you've already defined it previously - not a bad thing, just redundant.

Comment: Also, you may be able to remove *roomRefHandle* as it doesn't appear to be defined (maybe a class var?) but if your not removing the observer via the handle, it's not needed.

Comment: Yes, `roomRefHandle` is a class var and I deinit/remove observer. And you're right about those issues in my solution, I removed the `name.characters.count > 0` and the redundant declaration of `uid`. I put the revised function at the bottom of my question. `newRoomRef` sets the room into the "rooms" node. And thanks for the DB suggestion in your edit, I'm keen to try it that way - I guess it would be better to not have to store each room in two places (your suggestion involved removing the "rooms" node from each user, right?). But is the "true" necessary? .... cont'd

Comment: ... Couldn't I just have a list of users in the room node, without "true"? In your example, in Romper Room, "uid_1" isn't "false", it's just not there - which is how I have it set up currently.

Comment: @KingTim No, you can't just have a list of users - Firebase requires key:value pairs so to indicate a user belongs to a room, you would need the uid: true (key:value). You can also leverage that for populating a tableView datasource: i.e. when a user logs in, query the rooms node for all rooms where that users uid is true. That will return the rooms they belong to. It avoids having two copies of the room info and makes it easier to maintain as the room data is returned in the query (the room name) so you don't have to have second query to get the room name.

Comment: So the point of `observeRooms` is to read the user's rooms (both what's already there and listen for when that user creates a new room), and update the `usersRooms` array accordingly, which is used to populate the table with the user's rooms. If I changed my DB structure, and instead did that process by looking through ALL the rooms in the app, and seeing if the user's UID was included in the participants, wouldn't that be slower? As opposed to just keeping an eye on the much smaller list of only the current user's rooms?

Comment: Also, the listener part of the function wouldn't be the same either, wouldn't it have to listen for the user's UID being added somewhere in the massive list of rooms, instead of just listening for a room being added to the user's list of rooms?

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way, I accepted your answer because you've shed a good amount of light on the process.

Comment: @KingTim Consider: If you want to display a list of room names a user belongs you would store a reference to the room in the users node. So you then get that list. To then get the room names, you would have to iterate over that list and read in the room names from the rooms node. As you can see it's hitting Firebase twice. On the other hand, if you just query for the rooms the user is part of, even if there's 10k rooms, it will return everything you need almost instantly (very fast) and you've hit the database once. You'll also be notified of any changes - say the room owner removes someone.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Is there a question/reference for what a query like that would look like? I'm going to go back and try to refactor the app to work that way - so the `observeRooms` function will need to be changed to properly update the `usersRooms` array. It will have to go through all the rooms and check if the current user's uid is listed in the participants, correct? I've already changed the way rooms are created, now they only go into the "rooms" node, with participants being [uid : true], and users no longer have a "rooms" child.

Comment: I've been working on this and have changed the way rooms are entered into the DB, so the participants is [uid : true], and changed my observe function to observe the "rooms" node instead of the user's "rooms" (which I'm going to get rid of). I asked a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503726/how-to-check-a-firebase-subnode-for-a-specific-value-uid on how to check for the user's UID within the rooms' participants, I'm not clear on how that will be possible. Thanks again for all your input here!

Comment: Update, from the answer I got on that question is seems like I should be going back to how I had it before - with each user having their own list of rooms they belong to.

Comment: Your method makes sense and I understand that hitting firebase once is more efficient than twice, but it's looking like it will be harder than it seems to change the observer function to first look for the uid in all the room's participants, then grab the data from that room and update the array, hence the new question. I just don't see how that will work in this case. I've been re-reading your answer edit and I don't understand how `simply deep query on the rooms/users/ where uid_0 == true` will be implemented in this situation.

Comment: See my answer to your linked other question. I did the code for you. ;-)